# Possibility of using LDAP to form a Large Web Server by Multiple Small Servers

Tags: ldap, webserver, distributed-computing, openldap

Recently, I want to use openLDAP to build a large web server by using multiple small servers and I expect that it can support many users to use the services of the website. Is it possible to do it? Is there any other better solution to do the same thing? RADIUS?

Comment: You'd be surprised how many users a single OpenLDAP server will support, and you can easily federate them in a number of different ways. The usage patterns in LDAP are really different from those in a DBMS. Basically after the login there isn't any at all.

Answer (score 2):

A single LDAP server will probably hold as many users as your WEB server could handle. You would of course use the LDAP best practices of always having more than one server to meet your specific availability requirements.

Depending on your design requirements, you might want to consider some of the "Cloud" services for user store and Authentication.

LDAP implementations are more flexible than Radius and often in large Radius implementations Radius servers are simple a access protocol with the users being stored in LDAP.

Comment: So you mean that LDAP is so flexible for different usages and it is good enough for my requirements but depend on my design ?

Comment: The proper setup of the schema is important to achieve the results as dictated by the specific requirements.